# Get all text inside box in a preview camerax android

Tags: android, android-camerax

i want to analyse all text that is just inside by box that i have in a preview camera. But im getting wrong coordinates for text.
[image]

Validation is done on contains

```
class TestsPhotoscan : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private var scaleX = 1F
private var scaleY = 1F
private var rectCrop = Rect()
private var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider? = null
private lateinit var cameraProviderListenableFuture: ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    cameraProviderListenableFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

    // Request camera permissions
    if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
        startCamera()
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS,
            REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
        )
    }

    binding.borderView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            binding.borderView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            val points = IntArray(2)
            binding.borderView.getLocationOnScreen(points)
            rectCrop = Rect(
                points[0],
                points[1],
                points[0] + binding.borderView.width,
                points[1] + binding.borderView.height
            )
        }
    })
}


private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this, it
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

@SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
private fun startCamera() {

    cameraProviderListenableFuture.addListener(Runnable {
        cameraProvider = cameraProviderListenableFuture.get()
        binding.viewFinder.post { setupCamera() }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))

}

private fun buildPreviewUseCase(): Preview {
    val display = binding.viewFinder.display
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { display.getMetrics(it) }
    val preview = Preview.Builder()
        .setTargetRotation(display.rotation)
        .setTargetResolution(Size(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels))
        .build()
        .apply {
            setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
        }

    return preview
}

private fun setupCamera() {

    cameraProviderListenableFuture.addListener({

        // Preview
        val preview = buildPreviewUseCase()

        val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .build()
            .also {
                it.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                    { processImage(it) })
            }

        // Select back camera as a default
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        val useCaseGroup = UseCaseGroup.Builder()
            .addUseCase(preview)
            .addUseCase(imageAnalyzer)
            .build()

        try {
            // Unbind use cases before rebinding
            cameraProvider?.unbindAll()

            // Bind use cases to camera
            cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, useCaseGroup
            )

        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}

@SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
private fun processImage(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {

    setScaleFactor(imageProxy)
    recognizeText(
        InputImage. fromMediaImage(
            imageProxy.image!!,
            imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
        )
    ).addOnCompleteListener { imageProxy.close() }
}

private fun setScaleFactor(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
    val viewWidth = binding.viewFinder.width.toFloat()
    val viewHeight = binding.viewFinder.height.toFloat()
    val imageWidth = imageProxy.width.toFloat()
    val imageHeight = imageProxy.height

    scaleX = viewWidth / imageWidth
    scaleY = viewHeight / imageHeight
}

private fun recognizeText(image: InputImage): Task<Text> {

    val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS)

    return recognizer.process(image)
        .addOnSuccessListener(
            ScopedExecutor(TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD),
            OnSuccessListener<Text> {
                for (block in it.textBlocks) {
                    for (line in block.lines) {
                        for (element in line.elements) {
                            if (rectCrop.contains(
                                    translateX(element.boundingBox?.left ?: -1).roundToInt(),
                                    translateY(element.boundingBox?.top ?: -1).roundToInt()
                                )
                            ) {
                           
                            println(element.text)
                           }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            })
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            // finish()
        }
        return
    }
}


companion object {
    private const val TAG = "Mytag"
    private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
    private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
}

fun translateX(x: Int) =
    x * scaleX

fun translateY(y: Int) = y * scaleY
```

}

and layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout                                          
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
    android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/border_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_drawable"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/viewFinder"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   </layout>
```

Comment: Is `element.boundingBox` in screen coordinates or relative to the image? `getLocationOnScreen()` is in screen coordinates. If only the y coordinate is off, this may be the issue.

Comment: Boundingbox is about image. Both x and y are wrong

Comment: Ok. I didn't notice that `border_view` has a left margin. `x` would be off by the margin or however many pixels `16dp` is. I still think that you are mixing coordinates: screen coordinates (`getLocationOnScreen()` and view coordinates `element.boundingBox`.  I would test with scaleX and scaleY = 1.0 in case there is an issue with scaling.

Comment: Remove `match_parent` from border_view. It's not allowed. See comment [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#widgets-dimension-constraints). What is __background_drawable_? It looks like it should stretch across the entire width of the preview but doesn't.

Comment: bakcground drawable is my red rectangle shape.  Match_parent is allowed but not recommended.

Comment: Why doesn't your red rectangle span the entire view if its width is match_parent?

Comment: because i want margins on both side

Comment: I think your posted image is throwing me. Your border_view as margins of 16dp. I see way more than 16dp in the image on either side of the red rectangle.

Comment: Sorry, was just a paint example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty that you are having is getting a good mapping from the image in the *ImageProxy* to what is displayed by the *PreviewView*. Although this sounds easy, I don't believe there is straightforward way to do this mapping. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63902317/camerax-image-analysiss-imageproxy-size-and-previewview-size-are-not-the-same/63912198#63912198) to a similar question. I took a look at implementing each of the suggestions in this answer and, although they worked in some situations, they failed in others. Of course, I could have taken the wrong approach.

I have come to the conclusion that extracting and analyzing a bitmap extracted from the preview area and identifying those words that are completely enclosed by the red rectangle is the simplest. I circumscribe those words with their own red rectangle to show that they have been correctly identified.

[image]

The following is the reworked activity, a graphic overlay the produces the word boxes and the XML for the display. Comments are in the code. Good luck!

**TestPhotoscan.kt**

```
class TestsPhotoscan : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var wordFenceRect = Rect()
    private var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider? = null
    private lateinit var cameraProviderListenableFuture: ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        cameraProviderListenableFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS,
                REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
            )
        }
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, it
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
    private fun startCamera() {
        cameraProviderListenableFuture.addListener({
            cameraProvider = cameraProviderListenableFuture.get()
            binding.viewFinder.post { setupCamera() }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun buildPreviewUseCase(): Preview {
        val display = binding.viewFinder.display
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { display.getRealMetrics(it) }
        val rotation = display.rotation

        return Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(Size(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels))
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .build()
            .apply {
                setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
            }
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    private fun setupCamera() {
        cameraProviderListenableFuture.addListener({

            // Preview
            val preview = buildPreviewUseCase()

            val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .build()
                .also { it ->
                    it.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                        { processImage(it) })
                }

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            val useCaseGroup = UseCaseGroup.Builder()
                .addUseCase(preview)
                .addUseCase(imageAnalyzer)
                .build()

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider?.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, useCaseGroup
                )

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    private fun processImage(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        // This code will display the image available in the ImageProxy within an inset view
        // if the inset view is visible to the user.
        //
        // The source for ImageUtils is at
        // https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/translate-showcase/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/showcase/translate/util/ImageUtils.kt
        if (binding.insetView.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            var imageBitmap = ImageUtils.convertYuv420888ImageToBitmap(imageProxy.image!!)
            imageBitmap = rotateBitmap(imageBitmap, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees.toFloat())
            binding.insetView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
        }

        // PreviewViews allow access to a bitmap representation of what the preview shows. This is
        // just a whole lot easier than mapping the ImageProxy image to what the PreviewView
        // displays on the screen.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63912198/6287910
        binding.viewFinder.bitmap?.apply {
            recognizeText(
                InputImage.fromBitmap(this, 0)
            ).addOnCompleteListener { imageProxy.close() }
        }
    }

    private fun recognizeText(image: InputImage): Task<Text> {
        val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS)

        return recognizer.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                ScopedExecutor(TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD),
                {
                    binding.wordFence.clearBoxes()
                    binding.wordFence.getHitRect(wordFenceRect)
                    for (block in it.textBlocks) {
                        for (line in block.lines) {
                            for (element in line.elements) {
                                // For each word, check to make sure that the entire word is
                                // contained with the word fence.
                                if (isRectWithinRect(element.boundingBox, wordFenceRect)) {
                                    // Change the box boundary from the coordinate system of the
                                    // parent to the coordinates of the word fence.
                                    val outlineBox = Rect(element.boundingBox)
                                    outlineBox.offset(
                                        -binding.wordFence.left,
                                        -binding.wordFence.top
                                    )
                                    binding.wordFence.addBox(outlineBox)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    binding.wordFence.invalidate()
                })
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                // finish()
            }
            return
        }
    }

    private fun isRectWithinRect(enclosedRect: Rect?, enclosingRect: Rect) =
        enclosedRect != null && enclosingRect.contains(enclosedRect)

    private fun rotateBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, rotation: Float) =
        Matrix().run {
            preRotate(rotation)
            Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, this, true
            )
        }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "Applog"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }
}
```

**BoxedWordView.kt**

```
class BoxedWordView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val mBoxes = mutableListOf<Rect>()
    private val mPaint = Paint().apply {
        strokeWidth = 2f
        color = context.resources.getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light)
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    }

    override fun onDrawForeground(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDrawForeground(canvas)
        for (box in mBoxes) {
            drawBox(canvas, box)
        }
    }

    private fun drawBox(canvas: Canvas, box: Rect) {
        canvas.drawRect(box, mPaint)
    }

    fun addBox(box: Rect) {
        mBoxes.add(box)
    }

    fun clearBoxes() {
        mBoxes.clear()
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<layout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
            android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/insetView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

        <com.example.textrecognition.BoxedWordView
            android:id="@+id/wordFence"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_drawable"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/viewFinder"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/viewFinder"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/viewFinder"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/viewFinder" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I will mention that the app sometimes freezes when coming back from the "recents" list. I might have introduced that problem, but be aware of it.