# Android CameraX Text recognition start/stop on click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I would like to implement something simmilar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68777981/15014770), but instead of starting the analysis on creation of the app, I want to start and stop it with, for example press of a button. How can something like this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply introduce a flag to control whether processing camera frame in [ImageAnalysis.Analyzer#analyze](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis.Analyzer#analyze(androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy)) callback and then flip this flag in your button onclick listener?